# How to describe the following situation?

Tags: plural-forms, formal-language

There are four assumptions:

- User 1's location is initially x1, and is changed at speed of 5 m/s in a counterclockwise direction along a circular path with a radius 100 centered at O1.
- User 2's location is initially x2, and is changed at speed of 5 m/s in a counterclockwise direction along a circular path with a radius 100 centered at O2.
- User 3's location is initially x3, and is changed at speed of 5 m/s in a counterclockwise direction along a circular path with a radius 100 centered at O3.
- User 4's location is initially x4, and is changed at speed of 5 m/s in a counterclockwise direction along a circular path with a radius 100 centered at O4.

---

I'd like to express the above four sentences in a single formal sentence without misunderstanding.

> We assume that the locations of the 4 users are initially given as x1, x2, x3, and x4, respectively, and are changed at speeds of 5 meters per second in counterclockwise directions along circular paths with radii $250$ centered at O1, O2, O3, and O4, respectively.

Is the above sentence correct?
I can not judge whether I have correctly expressed.

Comment: I think if you lose the first *respectively* it reads fine and I would understand it.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a few phrase-separating commas to give the reader some idea of which concepts are being linked. Better yet, split the sentence into two - one to describe the initial condition and one to describe the rate of change:

> We assume that the locations of the 4 users are initially given as `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `x4` respectively. These locations are changed at speeds of 5 meters per second, in counter-clockwise directions, along circular paths with radii `250`, centered at O1, O2, O3, and O4, respectively.

It is now clear where the particles start and that `x_i` is linked with `O_ì` for i in [1,2,3,4]. It is also clear how they are moving, since you are giving a list of adjectives about the velocity.

Two sentences are not one, but speaking concisely helps the sentences to be comprehensible.